# How can I stop a comparator from oscillating in a relaxation oscillator configuration?

Tags: oscillator, comparator

I have a dual supply comparator and I want it to stop oscillating and output +12V with a single switch. I tried to connect R3 to +12V but it still oscillate with low frequency and like 95% duty cycle.

As the tile goes: How can I stop the comparator from oscillating with a single switch?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiURf9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What switch? What oscillation? LM393 is a "single supply" comparator; or do you mean that you've connected symmetrical supplies to it? What scope does this concern: is this about the simulation pictured, or a physical circuit? If physical, please show placement/layout.

Comment: @TimWilliams Any SPST switch, yes it is connected to ±12V, the question is clear.

Comment: Ok, so an enable. What level do you want the output at while disabled? What phase should it start at when enabled (if any)?

Comment: @TimWilliams I want the output to be HIGH (+12V) when disabled and the start phase doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjmjdn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Something like this will do.

Comment: Thanks, why did you increase the resistors value to 100K?

Comment: To give a squarer (~50%) wave for demonstration purposes. Note that R4 into R1+C1 and R2+R3 is a divider, reducing Vout(high) and giving it some tilt as C1 charges. The larger ratio gives a squarer output.

Comment: Is it okay to connect negative rail directly to inverting input or should I add a resistor in series?

Comment: LM393 won't mind zero ohms. Any resistance up to (but less than) R3 will do (assuming R1 = R2, or by ratio if otherwise).